# Multiple AudioTracks, Single Thread or Multiple?

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, threadpool

In my application, I will be creating multiple Audio Tracks, some of which will need to play simultaneously. I'm going to use `MODE_STREAM` and write data in as the app runs. Sounds are going to be dynamically generated, which is why I use Audio Track as opposed to anything else.
I have 4 options, I believe:

1. AsyncTask
2. One UI thread and one thread that manages all the AudioTrack playing
3. One UI thread and one thread for each AudioTrack
4. One UI thread and a [Thread Pool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)

Which of the four methods would be the best way to manage multiple AudioTracks?

I think Thread Pool is the way to go, but I'm not positive as I haven't actually used it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which way did you implement it?

Comment: @burakk I never got far on the app because (at least at the time), audio latency in Android was terrible (and I was inexperienced). If I did it now, I'd have one background thread because simultaneous audio processing from different threads was a stupid idea. And, I THINK that using one `AudioTrack` and correctly setting the data (frequency and whatnot) to combine the sounds would be the way to do it over trying to play multiple audio tracks. If you're interested in Android Audio development, check out columbia.edu [andraudio mailing list](http://music.columbia.edu/mailman/listinfo/andraudio)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I already developed an app that can play two streams simultaneously. I have two services each instantiating an AudioTrack in a separate thread. As I asked in my SO question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493521/multiple-audiotrack-instances-and-threads-in-a-single-service, I'd like to know what would be the best way to handle more than two streams. I don't want to write a service for each.

Comment: I'm not an expert in audio or hardware i/o, but I believe that as you add streams you will get an increase in congestion which could lead to unexpected/unwanted results. I may be wrong though. I'll take a look at your Q tomorrow if you haven't gotten an answer by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I was just creating a new thread every time I played an AudioTrack.

But, regardless it really doesn't matter. I found that when trying to play more than one AudioTrack at a time, there's a crackling/choppy sound. I believe this is just an issue with the Android system, not with my app.

As of API level 9 (gingerbread) I can apply a session id to an audio track, which I believe would let me play it with SoundPool, which should make the playing of multiple AudioTracks at once much smoother.

Right now, due to how many users are still on 2.2 and the fact that I don't have a gingerbread device, I will put this project aside until later.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet for this would be AsyncTask.

Comment: My concern is that AsyncTask creates a single worker thread, and if say, 4 AudioTracks are running on one worker thread, could that possibly make them block the entire thread?

Comment: One other concern is with AsyncTask `The task can be executed only once` per the docs. So would I be able to dynamically change the AudioTrack information through an onTouch event? I also currently lack experience with AsyncTask because the one app I've released had no need for it.

Comment: You can execute the task more than once by calling "AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask();  task.execute();

Comment: Okay, thank you. But that would still create a lot of unnecessary overhead for the repeated task creation, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Create an AsyncTask for every AudioTrack, and execute them with an Excecutor (on my Android 4.4, only the first task will be executed, if no Excecutor is used). 
Here is an example of streaming a microphone signal to AudioTrack and a audio file stream to an other AudioTrack in parallel.

```
/** Task for streaming file recording to speaker. */
private class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<Null, Null, Null> {
    private short[] buffer;
    private int bufferSize;
    private final AudioTrack audioTrack;
    ...
    @Override
    protected Null doInBackground(final Null... params) {
        ...
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        ...
    }
}

/** Task for streaming microphone to speaker. */
private class MicTask extends AsyncTask<Null, Null, Null> {
    private short[] buffer;
    private int bufferSize;
    private final AudioTrack audioTrack;
    ...
    @Override
    protected Null doInBackground(final Null... params) {
        ...
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        ...
    }
}

/** On the UI-thread starting both tasks in parallel to hear
    both sources on the speaker. **/
PlayerTask playerTask = new PlayerTask();
playerTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new Null());

MicTask micTask = new MicTask();
micTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new Null());
```