# Multiple AudioTrack Instances (and Threads) in a Single Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, audio-streaming, audiotrack

I have a streaming music application that can play two streams simultaneously by using two separate services utilizing one AudioTrack each, on their own threads. Now I'd like to able to play more than two streams, and I guess having more services is not the way to go.

Is it possible to have a single service having dynamically instantiated AudioTracks? How can I implement separate threads for each of the AudioTrack instances? How will I access the dynamically instantiated AudioTracks?

Comment: I'd really like to hear some advice about this...

Comment: hi burakk, I see your question has been asked a while ago. Have you found a good solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no...